# output filtered images to new folder and rename them

Tags: imagemagick, command-prompt, imagemagick-convert

I want to add some filters to all jpg images inside a folder using the terminal like this:

```
convert *.jpg -colorspace Gray -sharpen 0x4.0 {}.jpg
```

The above line of code works fine except one issue:

I have all images inside the folder with incrementing numbers like : `1.jpg` and `2.jpg`.

I want the new filtered images to go to a separate folder inside the current folder and rename them like `1-filtered.jpg` and `2-filtered.jpg`

How can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ImageMagick, you can do that as follows. Assume your images are in directory test1 and you want them in an existing directory called test2 within test1. So you change directories to test1 and run:

```
convert *.jpg -set filename:f "%t" -sharpen 0x4 "test2/%[filename:f]-filtered.jpg"
```

test2 must already exist. ImageMagick will not create a new directory.

"%t" gets the name without the suffix and puts it into variable f.